# Solving for the real component if provided the Angle and Imaginary value

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve for the Real component. However, using the tan(theta) never provides the real component rather it just returns 0 for the real component and a reduced imaginary value which doesn't make sense.

I think I may be doing something incorrectly, as it seems quite logical (to me at least) that it should be possible to get the real component.

**EDIT : I'm using j instead of i to denote the imaginary component.**

**The imaginary value is 0+75j; The angle is 26 degrees; Using tan(theta) to find the R (real component)**

[image]

Comment: The height of the triangle, in red, is $75$, not $75j$.

Comment: It defines the imaginary component. But it is 0 + 75j whereby the real component is 0 and the imaginary component is 75.

Comment: The complex number is $75j$, yes. But a geometric context uses real numbers, and the terms "height", "length", and "width" only make sense as real numbers. In particular, the equation $\tan \theta = O/A$ does not apply to complex $O$ and/or $A$, only to real perpendicular lengths. To do this with complex numbers directly, you would use $Re^{j \theta} = R \cos \theta + j R \sin \theta$ with $\theta = 64^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We normally write $z=x+yj$

The real part $Re(z)=x$

The imaginary part $Im(z)=yj$

We can also have the modulus $r=|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

and the argument $\theta$ where $\tan \theta =\frac y x$

It’s important to know that $Re(z)=r \cos \theta$ and that $Im(z)= r j\sin \theta$

You have the information that $\theta = 26$ so $75j =r j \sin 26$

Now find $r = \frac {75}{\sin 26}$

Then find $Re(z) =r\cos 26$

Comment: Thanks for that information. That helped me find the expression for the real x component:  75cos(26)/sin(26) which is just 75arctan(26). 

But your expression allowed me to cancel out the j component.

Comment: If you write $z=x+j\,y$ with $x,y \in \mathbb R$ then $Re(z)=\Re(z)=x$ and $Im(z)=\Im(z)=y$, so that $z = \Re(z)+j\, \Im(z)$. The imaginary unit $j$ is *not* part of $\Im(z)$, at least not when using the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Notation) [definitions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImaginaryPart.html).

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is the real value ($x$-axis) then

$$\tan(26º) = \frac{R}{75}.$$

Comment: The issue I have is that the Imaginary component does not have a real component. I.e (0+75j)

Comment: I don't understand your question completely, but I assume that $\textbf{they added}$ a real component such that the new  value in the complex plane is $(R i +75 j)$ (with $R$ to be found).

Comment: Sorry, I think it might be because I'm using j to denote the imaginary component. It would be R + 75i, and I would like to find R.